# Struggling a little with .vimrc and marks

Tags: vim

Summary:

```
let @c = "dd/##completed <CR> p"
```

Is not working, any suggestions?

---

I have recorded a macro which deletes a line, moves to another line (my ##completed section)and pastes the line to here.

This was working fine until I realised that the mark ('c - which directs to my ##completed section) does not stick to the text, but to the line itself (obvious now I think of it).

So instead I have altered my .vimrc to perform a search for the line ##completed and paste the contents below it.

The code is as follows...

```
let @c = "dd/completed <CR> p"
```

But this does not work, instead I am presented with "/completed  p" inside my command line .  So it seems that the vimrc is not processing the carriage return correctly, do I have the syntax wrong here?

Or if this is a terrible way of moving lines around, can anyone offer a better alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't fully understand your mapping, but you need to write `\<CR>` inside double quotes to get a carriage return; the backslash is missing. Alternatively, you can directly insert it via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (or <kbd>Q</kbd> on many Windows installations), followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

Generally, I wouldn't preset a register (`c`, what you mistakenly refer to as "mark") in your .vimrc; if you need this often, define a mapping via `:nnoremap`. You can assign mappings to any free key sequence (and with `<Leader>`; i.e. backslash, you have a free starting key), but you only have 26 named registers.

---

For moving text, look into the `:move` command. This might do what you want:

```
:move /##completed
```

Comment: This is great, just what I needed; the missing \<CR> was the issue

Comment: Thanks for your edit, this is a much more elegant solution than mine.

Comment: Ok, I have changed this too: 

`:nnoremap <C-c> :move /Completed<CR>`

...and all is well :)

Comment: Glad I could help. That mapping looks fine, though I personally wouldn't use `<C-c>` for it.